# Search Results shows blank popout

Tags: search-results

I can't figure out why the search results for pages (publishing pages) show the popout as blank when you hover over the result set.  I have the March 2015 CU installed.
[image: Search_Result_Hover_Shows_Blank]

Comment: Have you tried any other browser? It's an iframe so it could be any setting in your browser.

Comment: I have tried FireFox and it does the same.  This is all OOB Setup at this point.  So I don't know what else it could be. I've deleted the Search App and Re-built it and still got the same results.  Stumped.

Comment: It looks like you does not even get any "results under this site" suggestion under the iframe either..  Is this a global search center? Can you try to create a new search center from scratch to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Well, I have tried that and I get the same results.  The content is found in the search results, its just the "Hover" panel doesn't show anything.  I will continue to investigate.

Comment: There has been no changes to any display template either?

Comment: Correct.  The search is Out of Box at the moment.  No customizations have been done.  I'm also re-running PSConfig right now.

Comment: is it behaving same for documents as well? do you have office web apps? are you trying from server or from pc?

Comment: OK, This is a Test Farm.  So everything is on one Server.  I don't have OWA installed and yes is does the same for documents as well as Publishing Pages.  The search result return items found as you can see. Its the hover panel that is empty.  There are no customizations.

Comment: Are the URLs of the Search Center and the Search Result the same host web application?

Comment: The URLs are the same.  I'm also using Host-Header Web Applications.  I am beginning to think there maybe some conflicting software installed?  I also checked the Service accounts (SPSearchSvc in this case) and the permissions are correct (Full Read).